# Potential energy term in lagrangian of waves on a string

Tags: waves, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, string, elasticity

I'm going through  Quantum Field for the Gifted Amateur, in example 1.4, the wave equation is derived through the Lagrangian. A key fact used is that, the potential energy equation is given as:

$$ V = \frac12 \int_0^l dx T (\partial_x \Phi)^2$$

Where $\Phi$ is the equation of the wave, $T$ is the tension in the string, and $l$ is length of string. I am quite confused as how this expression was arrived at, could someone explain?

Comment: Note that the string is stretched in _two_ directions. That is, in the horizontal $x$ direction, and the perpendicular $\psi$ direction. Since U=tension$\times$distance stretched, a little calculus will help you get the above expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive it purely from symmetry arguments. Assuming that the potential energy is local:
$$
V = \int dx v(x,\phi,\partial_x\phi,...)
$$
Invariance by spatial translation kills the $x$ dependence and the invariance of field translation kills the $\phi$ dependence. Then, you typically assume it to be harmonic in $\phi$, as a quadratic approximation when $\phi$ is small. Going in Fourier space:
$$
V = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \frac{f(k)}{2}|\hat \phi|^2
$$
Finally, taking a quadratic approximation for $f$, motivated by small $k$ (or equivalently long range behaviour), you get the desired energy.

Another way is to start from discrete version of coupled harmonic oscillators. Your $\phi(x)$ is now $\phi_n$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$. The potential is (only nearest neighbour coupling for simplicity):
$$
V = \frac{k}{2}\sum (\phi_n-\phi_{n+1})^2
$$
In the continuum limit, let $a\to0$ be the lattice spacing:
$$
\phi_n = \phi(na)\\
k = \frac{T}{a}
$$
you get:
$$
\frac{k}{2}\sum (\phi_n-\phi_{n+1})^2 \to \frac{T}{2}\int \partial_x\phi^2dx
$$

Hope this helps.